# Ansible to create a Google Cloud SQL instance

Tags: ansible, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am using Ansible for deployment of Google compute engine instances. I have a requirement to use Google Cloud SQL instance [MySQL], which is the managed database in Google-cloud solution.

Is there a way/module available in Ansible for creating and managing Google-cloud-Sql instance?

Comment: There's nothing in the [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/list_of_cloud_modules.html#google) and the [development branch on Github](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/tree/devel/cloud/google) isn't showing anything either so doesn't look like it.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing in the [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/list_of_cloud_modules.html#google) and the [development branch on Github](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/tree/devel/cloud/google) isn't showing anything either so it doesn't look like there's a module available for your use right now.

One option is to simply shell out to do this with something like this:

```
- name: create google-cloud sql instance
  shell: >
    gcloud sql instances create \
      --activation-policy="{{ activation_policy }}" \
      --tier="{{ tier }}" \
      --pricing-plan="{{ pricing_plan }}" \
      --region="{{ region }}" \
      --gce-zone="{{ gce_zone }}" \
      --database-version="{{ mysql_version }}" \
      --backup-start-time= \
      "{{ instance_id }}"
```

Which is simply following the instructions in [Google's docs for Google Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/create-instance).

Alternatively you could create the module yourself and raise a pull request on the [Ansible core modules repo](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/tree/devel/cloud/google).

Comment: Thanks, time being i will use shell: to run the command. I will try to create a module in ansible, if I get a free time :)

Comment: I had a prod around github last night and Ansible's GCE modules are built on top of libcloud which in turn builds on the GCE python SDK. Unfortunately it looks like there isn't any SDKs for the cloud SQL stuff, just command line and REST API so I'm not sure if the Ansible maintainers would be comfortable with accepting a pull request to add a module for this

Answer (score 3):

Check [Ansible 2.8/latest doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/gcp_sql_instance_module.html).
There is a module for creating GCP CloudSQL instance & database:

**TASK**

```
- name: Create GCP CloudSQL instance
  gcp_sql_instance:
    name: '{{ sql_instance.name }}'
    backend_type: '{{ sql_instance.backend_type }}'
    database_version: '{{ sql_instance.database_version }}'
    settings:
      tier: '{{ sql_instance.tier }}'
    region: '{{ sql_instance.region }}'
    project: '{{ project_id }}'
    auth_kind: '{{ authentification_type }}'
    service_account_file: '{{ credentials_file }}'
    state: present
```

**VARIABLES**

```
### authentification
# authentification_type: application / machineaccount / serviceaccount
# service_account_file: "/path/to/auth.json"
project_id: []
authentification_type: serviceaccount
credentials_file: []

### Cloud_SQL instance specifications
# backend_type: FIRST_GEN / SECOND_GEN / EXTERNAL
# database_version: MYSQL_5_5 / MYSQL_5_6 / MYSQL_587 / POSTGRESQL_9_6
# tier: db-g1-smal / db-pg-g1-small / custom-2-2048
sql_instance:
  name: []
  backend_type: []
  database_version: []
  region: []
  tier: []
```